# Java JXLS API ForEach

Tags: java, xls, jxls

I am using JXLS API for generating Excel reports. I am trying to achieve nested loops in such a way that I want to ***iterate FIRST column-wise*** the array of OuterObjects, where each OuterObject has an array for InternalObject, and then ***iterate SECOND row-wise*** the array of InternalObjects. Below is the template Expression Language used: requirement

```
| <jx:forEach items="teams" var="team"> | <jx:forEach items="team.employees" var="employee"> | </jx:forEach> |

|                                       | ${employee.leaveDates}                             |               | 
|                                       | </jx:forEach>                                      |               |
```

Assuming I have **m** teams and each team has **n** employees, my excel should be **m x n** table. However, using the above template I'm able to achieve only **1 x 1** table.

Can anyone help me to correct my Expression Language?